# CSS for element not in focus, not active, and not being hovered over

Tags: css

I want to set a property on a checkbox when it is not in focus, not active, and not being hovered over.  Would the following work?

```
.ui-chkbox-box:not(:focus):not(:active):not(:hover) {
       background: white;
}
```

If not, how to do it?  Thanks for any help

Comment: Isn't that the default state? That said, have you tried it...and what happened?

Comment: It's not recognizing it.  I think I may have figured out the problem.  The CSS is on a child component in Angular.  I think I have to put it in the parent component.

Comment: The code, as written works, I just had to move it to the child component.